# Libgdx sprite ring object passing through it

Tags: object, graphics, libgdx, sprite

How is it possible object can pass through ring spirte like in the image below?

[image: Object through ring sprite]

Please can you help me I have no idea how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you posted a incorrect image. To get the image you posted you just have to draw the red bar on top of the black ring.

I guess you want the ring on the left side to be on top and the right side to be over so it visually goes through. Well this is simply not so easy in 2D since draw order.

I have a couple of suggestion you can explore.

- Always draw the ring on top of the bar but when a collision is happening you calculate where the bar overlaps and don't draw the pixels in that place. You can use a `Pixmap` for calculations like this. Depending on the size of your images this could be very expensive to calculate each frame.
- A faster but slightly more hacky way could be to split red bar in multiple images and if a certain part of it should be overlapped by the ring draw it first otherwise draw it after the ring. Depending on what the red bar is going to look in your end product and how much possible angles the bar could have I can imagine this can be very tricky to get right.
- Use 3D for this. You could have a billboard with a slight angle for the ring and have the bar locked on the distance axis at the rings center. However, on certain angles of entrance and exit you will get Z fighting since the pixels will be at the same distance from the camera. This might or might not be noticable and I have no idea how LibGDX would handle Z fighting.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna add this solution : 
if the object gonna pass through the ring horizontally i propose to devise sprite ring in to to sprite (sprite 1 & sprite 2)

[image]

you just have to draw sprites in that order :

- Sprite1
- Sprite Object
- Sprite2

You can do the same if the object is gonna pass through ring vertically

PS : this solution don't work if the object is going to passs through ring both Vertically and Horizontally

Hope this was helpfull

Good luck